# How to force Mysql to use primary Index in IN clause...?

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing, where-in

```
    Query1. SELECT * FROM traffic WHERE id IN (1904817,1904699,1882859);

    Query2. SELECT * FROM traffic WHERE id IN 
            (SELECT id FROM data_table where condition=1);
```

Here traffic table having nearly a million record, and `id` is the primary key.

Query1 using index `id`

where as in Query2 it is not using the index .

what to be done to run Query2 efficently... by using index...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `inner join` instead of `IN` and make another index on `condition column`:

```
select t.* from traffic t
inner join data_table d on t.id = d.id and d.contition = 1
```

Answer (score 3):

and the barbaric way: `SELECT * FROM traffic, data_table WHERE traffic.id=data_table.id`

Answer (score 1):

By specifying USE INDEX (index_list), you can tell MySQL to use only one of the named indexes to find rows in the table.

```
SELECT * FROM traffic USE INDEX (ID_INDEX) WHERE id IN 
            (SELECT id FROM data_table where condition=1);
```

Comment: Chances are MySQL will keep on treating the subquery as dependent, and thus will keep having miserable performance, though...

Comment: Please share your execution plan.